# fpdf cell positioning from array

Tags: arrays, fpdf, multiple-columns

I have an array named Array with its elements: A, B ,C,D,...,Z

I wanna generated a pdf using FPDF which will shows as below:

```
Elements in Array:   A | B | C
                     D | E | F
                     .........
                     X | Y | Z
```

The code above only shows elements in a single column. I have no idea how to make it to display as i desire. Please help.

```
$pdf->Cell('50','0','Elements in Array:',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell('50','0',' '.$Array[0],0,0,'L'); 
$pdf->Ln(5);
for($i=1;$i<=count($Array);$i++)
{
    $pdf->Cell('50','0','',0,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell('50','0','  '.$Array[$i],0,0,'L');   
    $pdf->Ln(5);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic approach; you can work out the details for yourself.

Instead of $i++, use $i += 3, so that each iteration deals with 3 elements of the array. Then, in each iteration, call Cell 3 times, one for each of the three columns. Draw lines, too if you want. (The subscripts you'll use for the 3 elements are $i, $i + 1, and $i + 2.)

Each row of 3 Cells should be positioned at $y. With each iteration, increment $y by whatever spacing seems to work best.

Since the total number of elements isn't necessarily divisible by 3, you'll have to test $i to avoid referencing a nonexistent element, and then break out of the loop.